# Jenkins Job not execute Protractor tests good

Tags: jenkins, protractor

I have Protractor tests, and I run tests with command tests with  `protractor protractor.conf.js --suite full` in VS code on my local. VS code run chrome instance and executed tests well. 
After that I setup Jenkins job for Protractor tests. My steps:

- Pull code form BitBucket
- Execute windows command `npm install`
- Executed windows command `node_modules\.bin\ng e2e --webdriver-update`

Jenkins opened chrome browser on `http://localhost:49156/ **` and start with Protractor tests.
On Chrome browser my tests could to find element by `ID,HTML,text`, but when needed to click on element I have this error  `[31m- [39m[31mFailed: element not interactable`.
This is piece of console output:

```
[15:37:51] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.buttonText("Create") - the first result will be used
  Creating configuration for 
    [31mÃ— Creating default configuration [39m
      [31m- [39m[31mFailed: element not interactable
        (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)
        (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088 (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT 6.2.9200 x86_64)[39m
        (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)
        (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088 (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT 6.2.9200 x86_64)
          at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\newGen_protractor\NewGenProject\ui\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546:15)
          at parseHttpResponse (C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\newGen_protractor\NewGenProject\ui\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
          at doSend.then.response (C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\newGen_protractor\NewGenProject\ui\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30)
          at <anonymous>
          at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
      From: Task: WebElement.click()
```

This is the Protractor tests:

```
it('Creating default configuration 2000 ', () => {
        _home.get2000Configuration().click();
        _descriptionModal.buttonStartCreate().click();
        for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            _wizardModal.buttonNext().click();
        }
        _descriptionModal.buttonCreate().click();
        expect(_configurationView.getBaImage().isDisplayed()).toBe(true).then(function (result) {
            expect(_configurationView.getNeb().count()).toBe(2);
            expect(_configurationView.getmage().count()).toBe(2);
            expect(_configurationView.getEngineImage().isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
        });
    });
```

Comment: If you page is responsive, considering  browser on jenkins with small screen size which lead same page opened with different layout.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the error stack that you posted I can see this:

```
[15:37:51] W/element - more than one element found for locator by.buttonText("Create") - the first result will be used
```

My guess is that has more than one button with this "Create" text and your code is getting lost. I would suggest check upon the button names and make sure that only one has this "Create" label, for example.